# Galois group of polynomials over p-adic Fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, galois-theory, p-adic-number-theory, solvable-groups

I had a beginners course in Algebra in which we did some GaloisTheory. We learned that in a field with charateristic 0, the Galoisgroup of a polynomial of degree n is isomorphic to a subgroup of the symmetric group $S_n. $ Besides as far as I can remember, in a Field with characteristic 0, every non-constant polynomial with degree less than 5 is solvable by radicals. Besides, we noted, that if this polynomial is solvable by radicals, its GaloisGroup is solvable as well.

Now my question is: I’m doing some research in p-adic field theory, and I’m looking for potential Isomorphism Types of Galois Groups of irreducible polynomials with degree $2,3 \ \text{or }\ 4. $ Using my knowledge from my beginners course in Algebra, can I thus say, in this case the only possible Galois groups are the solvable subgroups of $S_2, S_3\ \text{ and }\ S_4 $?

Comment: Every subgroup of $S_2, S_3, S_4$ is solvable, that's part of how the degree $5$ stuff works. For irreducible polynomials you also need the subgroup to be transitive.

Comment: So for degree 2 I only have $S_2 $ , for degree 3 its $A_3 $ and $S_3 $, degree 4 we have $A_4 $, $S_4 $, $D_4 $ , $V_4 $ and $C_4 $

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: I couldnt figure out why a subgroup must be transitive if the polynomial is irreducible. Is there an easy answer to that?

Comment: If $O$ is an orbit of the Galois action then every coefficient of $\prod_{r_i \in O}(x - r_i)$ is $G$-invariant. So the orbits of the Galois action on the roots of a polynomial correspond precisely to its factorization into irreducibles. Hence if the polynomial itself is irreducible there must be exactly one orbit. This is a standard Galois theory argument.